# JTextfield not focusable/editable on Mac

Tags: java, macos, swing, lwjgl, jtextfield

We are making a project in OpenGL using lwjgl3.  Our application has a button 'Add Cube' which opens a new JFrame containing 4 JTextFields and 2 JButtons, the layout for this JFrame is made using GroupLayout.  My friends who are running our project on Windows/Linux can select and edit these JTextFields without any problem, yet me, using MacOS High Sierra, can't.

When I open the JFrame none of the textfields are selected, they do register clicks (textField.setText when mouse clicked works), but they never grab focus, the flashing |-beam never appears, despite all my best efforts (it's been weeks now).  When I try to type something in the fields (neglecting the absence of the |-beam) the text appears in my current project file instead (where my cursor last was before running the project).  I added other classes who use JTextField's, when I run their main method they work fine yet when I instantiate these classes somewhere in our project the frame does open but the textfields are yet again not selectable.

Here I provide the CubeAdderPanel class, I have trimmed it down a bit.

*Updated according to replies*

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement;

import sourcecode.visualization.objects.Cube;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class CubeAdderPanel extends JFrame {

private JTextField textFieldX;
private JTextField textFieldY;
private JTextField textFieldZ;
private JTextField textFieldSize;

private SolidButton addButton;
private SolidButton backButton;

private JLabel lblX;
private JLabel lblY;
private JLabel lblZ;
private JLabel lblSize;

private Font font = new Font("Open Sans Light", Font.PLAIN, 13);

private Map<JTextField, Double> textInput = new HashMap<>();

private final MenuHandler handler;

public CubeAdderPanel(MenuHandler handler){

    this.handler = handler;

    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    setType(Type.UTILITY);
    setResizable(false);
    setUndecorated(true);
    setBounds(1370, 130, 280, 210);

    String osName = System.getProperty("os.name");
    if (osName.contains("Mac")) {
        setBounds(1130, 40, 280, 240);
    }

    initTextFields();
    initButtons();
    initLabels();

    //initFocusTraversal();
    initTextInputMap();
    initTextActions();

    //Creates JFrame layout
    JSeparator separator = new JSeparator();
    GroupLayout gl_panel = new GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    gl_panel.setHorizontalGroup(
            gl_panel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(Alignment.TRAILING, gl_panel.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(47)
                            .addGroup(gl_panel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING)
                                    .addGroup(gl_panel.createSequentialGroup()
                                            .addComponent(addButton, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 76, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                            .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 31, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                            .addComponent(backButton, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 76, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                    .addGroup(gl_panel.createSequentialGroup()
                                            .addGroup(gl_panel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                                                    .addComponent(lblX)
                                                    .addComponent(lblY, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 8, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                    .addComponent(lblZ)
                                                    .addComponent(lblSize))
                                            .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 26, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                            .addGroup(gl_panel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                                                    .addComponent(textFieldSize, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                    .addComponent(textFieldX, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                    .addComponent(textFieldY, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                    .addComponent(textFieldZ, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
                            .addGap(42))
                    .addGroup(gl_panel.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(separator, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 279, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addContainerGap(GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    gl_panel.setVerticalGroup(
            gl_panel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(gl_panel.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(35)
                            .addGroup(gl_panel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                                    .addComponent(lblX)
                                    .addComponent(textFieldX, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addGroup(gl_panel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                                    .addComponent(textFieldY, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addComponent(lblY))
                            .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addGroup(gl_panel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                                    .addComponent(textFieldZ, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addComponent(lblZ))
                            .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addGroup(gl_panel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                                    .addComponent(lblSize)
                                    .addComponent(textFieldSize, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGap(18)
                            .addComponent(separator, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addGap(15)
                            .addGroup(gl_panel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                                    .addComponent(backButton, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 27, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addComponent(addButton, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 27, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addContainerGap(46, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    getContentPane().setLayout(gl_panel);
}

private void initTextInputMap() {
    double empty = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    textInput.put(textFieldX, empty);
    textInput.put(textFieldY, empty);
    textInput.put(textFieldZ, empty);
    textInput.put(textFieldSize, empty);
}

private void saveTextInput(JTextField textField) {
    try {
        textInput.put(textField, Double.parseDouble(textField.getText()));
        getFocusOwner().transferFocus();
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        textField.setText("");
        textInput.put(textField, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
    } finally {
        boolean validInputs = hasValidInputs();
        if (! hasValidInput(textField)) {
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        }
        addButton.setEnabled(validInputs);
    }
}

private void saveTextInputs() {
    for (JTextField textField : textInput.keySet()) {
        saveTextInput(textField);
    }
}

private void initTextActions() {
    for (JTextField textField : textInput.keySet()) {
        textField.addActionListener((ActionEvent a) -> {
                    saveTextInput(textField);
        });
    }
}

private void initFocusTraversal() {
    getContentPane().setFocusTraversalPolicy(
            new SimpleFocusTraversalPolicy(
                    textFieldX, textFieldY, textFieldZ,
                            textFieldSize));
}

private void initTextFields() {
    textFieldX = new JTextField();
    textFieldX.setColumns(10);
    textFieldX.setName("X");

    textFieldY = new JTextField();
    textFieldY.setColumns(10);
    textFieldY.setName("Y");

    textFieldZ = new JTextField();
    textFieldZ.setColumns(10);
    textFieldZ.setName("Z");

    textFieldSize = new JTextField();
    textFieldSize.setColumns(10);
    textFieldSize.setName("Size");
}

private void initButtons() {
    addButton = new SolidButton("add");
    addButton.addActionListener((ActionEvent a) -> {
        saveTextInputs();
        if (!hasValidInputs()) {
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
            cleanInvalidInputs();
        } else {
            float x = textInput.get(textFieldX).floatValue();
            float y = textInput.get(textFieldY).floatValue();
            float z = textInput.get(textFieldZ).floatValue();
            float size = textInput.get(textFieldSize).floatValue();
            Cube cube = new Cube(x, y, z, size, 360, 1);
            handler.addCube(cube);
            resetInputs();
        }
    });

    addButton.setFont(font);

    backButton = new SolidButton("back");
    backButton.addActionListener((ActionEvent a) -> {
        setVisible(false);
        handler.restoreMenu();
    });
    backButton.setFont(font);
}

private void initLabels() {...}

private int counter = 1;

@Override
public void setVisible(boolean state) {
    super.setVisible(state);
    addButton.setEnabled(!state);
    if (state) {
        if (counter == 1) {
            counter = 0;
            super.setVisible(true);
        }
        textFieldX.requestFocus();
    }
}

public void terminate() {
    dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
}

private boolean hasValidInputs() {...}

private void cleanInvalidInputs() {...}

private boolean hasValidInput(JTextField textField) {...}

public void resetInputs() {...}
```

Thank you!!  If any additional information is required I'll be happy to provide!

EDIT:

This simple TextField class provides a perfectly editable/focusable JTextField when I run JTextField.main().

```
package sourcecode.visualization.GUI;

import javax.swing.*;

public class TextField {

JFrame frame = new JFrame("Jtextfield demo");
JTextField textField = new JTextField("Hello from JTextField", 10);

public TextField() {
    frame.add(textField);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new TextField();
        }
    });
}
```

Yet when I call the TextField from anywhere inside our project it never is editable/focusable when I run Main.main(), despite trying all focus related functions etc, e.g. here I added a TextField object to our Pilot class.

```
....
import sourcecode.visualization.GUI.TextField;

public class Pilot implements ILogic {

  TextField textField = new TextField();
....}
```

So this makes me believe the problem originates from an other class, not the CubeAdderPanel class, interfering with the JTextFields/swing, yet I don't know which one could cause this problem, we have looked in all of them, because all our code seems correct as it runs fine on Windows and Linux.  Could it be the Shader, Mesh, Window, Renderer... class? What can cause this problem?

Comment: It is very hard to understand. please reformat it.

Comment: [mcve] please...

Comment: I doubt this is related to the problem you're experiencing, but you shouldn't be using `KeyListener` and `MouseListener` to capture events from the text fields and buttons. You should be using `ActionListener` in both cases. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html andhttps://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html

Comment: Test your code without the custom focus traversal.

Comment: Hi guys!  Thanks for the help, I updated the program to use ActionListeners,  thank you for that. I also implemented FocusTraversalOnArray again, we used it before our simplification, unfortunately they didn't solve the problem.  I will now provide the problem in a minimal example. (Edited the question)

Comment: @camickr Thanks for the comment, we have tried this before, yet it doesn't change anything. I updated the question. :)